# Perl - Convert Number to 2 Decimal

Tags: perl, number-formatting

I want to convert a number to a decimal. I've been using:

```
sprintf("%02d", $price / 12);
```

Only sometimes `$price` is a whole number, so instead of `6`, I get `06`. How do I ensure that it converts to 2 decimal places, but also doesn't prepend a zero before the whole number ?

Comment: That seems to add a space before the number:

' 6' as opposed to '6'

Comment: `perldoc -f sprintf`, look for `flags`

Comment: Just for clarity - I've read the Perl doc. Flag either justifies it to the left, right or uses zeros. I want neither. I want a whole number to be simply '6' and a decimal such as '6.22222222222' to be '6.22'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sprintf('%.2f', $price/12) =~ s/\.00\z//r       # 5.14+
```

or

```
do { my $s = sprintf('%.2f', $price/12); $s =~ s/\.00\z//; $s }
```

For both of the above,

- If `$price/12 == 5.999`, evaluates to `6`
- If `$price/12 == 6`, evaluates to `6`
- If `$price/12 == 6.001`, evaluates to `6`
- If `$price/12 == 6.2`, evaluates to `6.20`
- If `$price/12 == 6.22`, evaluates to `6.22`
- If `$price/12 == 6.222`, evaluates to `6.22`
- If `$price/12 == 6.229`, evaluates to `6.23`

Comment: Ah I see. Your regular expression doesn't appear to be valid, but I get the idea. You want to convert it to two decimal place and then chop off the .00.

Comment: @snakespan How does it not?  Assign it -- `$p = (sprintf(..) =~ s/../../r);` -- right?

Comment: @zdim, They probably don't have 5.14. The second version wasn't part of my answer when snakespan wrote their message.

Answer (score 0):

```
int( $price / 6 + 0.5 );
```

Perl automatically changes between string and numbers as needed.